# counter on for loop, reporting 1

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, counter

I am simply trying to add a counter around my `for` loop, to count how many files are in my directory per qualification of the contains '`VCCS`'... the logic is working for the iterating, as it's iterating through my directory the amount of times I have a file in... however my counter keeps reporting 1. Relevant lines are `files_in_directory` market with comment `# here`.

I am getting this warning in PyLint: Constant name "`files_in_directory" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming stylepylint(invalid-name)` , on `files_in_directory = 0`

*I've tried moving the set 0, above the for and try, any thoughts?*

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
        files_in_directory = 0 # here
        for filename in os.listdir(config.DIRECTORY_LOCATION):
            if filename.__contains__('VCCS'):
                old_stdout = sys.stdout
                log_file = open("./logs/metrics.log","w")
                sys.stdout = log_file
                files_in_directory += 1 # here

                PENDING_RECORDS = FindPendingRecords().get_excel_data()
                # Do operations on PENDING_RECORDS

                # Reads excel to map data from excel to vital
                MAP_DATA = FindPendingRecords().get_mapping_data()

                # Configures Driver
                VITAL_ENTRY = VitalEntry()

                # Start chrome and navigate to vital website
                VITAL_ENTRY.instantiate_chrome()

                # Begin processing Records
                VITAL_ENTRY.process_records(PENDING_RECORDS, MAP_DATA)

                print(f"Date: ")
                print (str(currentDT))                
                print(f"Files in Directory #{files_in_directory}") # here

                sys.stdout = old_stdout
                log_file.close()  

    except Exception as exc:
        # print(exc)
        raise
```

Comment: You don't need to attach `log_file` to `sys.stdout` as `print` takes a `file` kwarg: `print('some string', file=log_file)`

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your problem using a simple example: `import os; my_count=0; for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()): if file.__contains__('.txt.'): my_count+=1; print(f"{my_count}")`

Comment: *I have tried moving the set 0, above the for and try* If you were resetting the count to 0 in the for loop, that would *definitely* cause it to report `1` every time

Comment: @C.Nivs no it is also reporting just 1 as stands.

Comment: Is anything modifying/using a `global files_in_directory`? I'm not sure where it would be getting reset otherwise

Comment: I'll put my suggested debug in an answer, as it will be a bit cumbersome as a comment. As a head's up, it will probably *not* be a direct answer to your question, but an easier way of reading what steps you need to take

Comment: What I would recommend is adding in the code that you are calling such as `get_excel_data`. As it sits, it doesn't look like those take any params, so I have a feeling those functions are modifying global variables

Answer (score 2):

### Note: This is to take place of many comments in the interest of readability

Your question as it sits is not an MCVE. To make it more succinct and to identify the *exact* cause:

```py
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Remove try block, just let it raise an error
    my_counter = 0

    for file in os.listdir("some_directory"):
        # you don't need to call the __contains__ method
        # as the 'in' keyword will invoke that for you
        if "VCCS" in file:

            # increment your counter first
            my_counter += 1
            print(file, my_counter)
```

Now there is no question what is modifying `my_counter`, and this will print out the file you are looking at, alongside the counter.

Once you've ironed out that behavior, you can start adding in your other functions

```py
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Remove try block, just let it raise an error
    my_counter = 0

    for file in os.listdir("some_directory"):
         if 'VCCS' in file:
             my_counter += 1
             print(my_counter, file)

             # Add functions back in one by one
             PENDING_RECORDS = FindPendingRecords().get_excel_data()
```

Continue this process until you identify *what* is causing your behavior. As it stands, I don't see anything explicit that could be overwriting that counter variable, so I suspect that either A) the code you posted does *not* reflect what is being run or B) you are modifying/resetting `files_in_directory` somewhere else in the module.

### Suggested Edit:

I would recommend you add in the other code from your module to see what's going on. That way we have a clearer picture of what's happening as your code runs

Answer (score -2):

So first thing first: you're sure you're passing the right directory, and that this directory contains indeed more than one file containing VCCS in their filename ?

I would also try to run this code without the Try/Except block, to see if you don't get some error after your first increment.

LMK what you get, I hope this helps.